# How to close all open terminal windows except the one running a shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'd like to know if it is possible to, when starting a shell script, close all other open console windows, without closing the one that runs the shell script.

I'm using Kubuntu's 16.04 konsole.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281589/how-to-close-all-open-terminal-windows-except-the-one-running-a-shell-script not solve the issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47281589/1391444

Comment: @JacobVlijm There is a policy regarding this: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1480/cross-posting-questions-that-are-on-topic-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites? It's certainly acceptable to post the same question on different SE sites, does it really matter how much time passed by between the postings? After all, the same question received two very different answers now…

Comment: Yes, there is a policy on this, will look it up...

Comment: @dessert please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @JacobVlijm Shouldn't we then first determine which one is the acceptable question rather than just closing both?

Comment: @dessert Both will not happen if OP picks one to withdraw. The other one will then stay open. Neither one received any votes.

Comment: @JacobVlijm This one did receive votes but their sum is 0 currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>**This does not work with Wayland!** If you're using Ubuntu 17.10 or newer and didn't change to using Xorg at login, this solution isn't for you.</sup>

For tasks like this I use `xdotool`, you may need to install it first with:

```bsh
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Here's my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
search="--class xterm"
a=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid)
b="$(xdotool search $search getwindowpid %@)"
for i in $b; do
  [[ $a -ne $i ]] &&
  echo kill $i
done
```

As you didn't mention which terminal emulator you use I wrote the script for `xterm` here, but you can easily change this by modifying the quoted part in the second line. `--class xterm` is a `xdotool --search` option that matches windows of the `xterm` window class. Read the “WINDOW COMMANDS” section of [`man xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdotool.1.html#contenttoc5) to get to know about those options, to test them use

```bsh
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid
```

to get the active terminal window's PID and

```bsh
xdotool search YOUROPTIONS getwindowpid %@
```

to get the PIDs of all windows matching `YOUROPTIONS`, e.g.

```bsh
xdotool search --all --name yourwindowsname --desktop 1 --class getwindowpid %@
```

to match all windows with the name `yourwindowsname` residing on desktop `1`. `--all` means that both conditions have to be met (logical “and”), the default is `--any` with the opposite meaning.

When you're all set and the script outputs the correct commands, remove `echo` from it to perform the `kill` actions.

---

It turns out for KDE's `konsole` the PID reported by `xdotool` is the same for every window, so we need this slightly different approach:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
search="--onlyvisible --class konsole"
a=$(xdotool getactivewindow) 
b="$(xdotool search $search)" 
for i in $b; do
  [[ $a -ne $i ]] &&
  xdotool windowclose $i
done
```

Comment: I tried using your code but It is not working. When I use `getwindowpid` it returns only one result. And also no window is closed. If i remove this option, so I get a list of IDs (I assume) but it also do not close any window. What could be wrong here? This is how I search  `b=$(xdotool search --class "konsole")`

Comment: Oh! I missed that! But, it returns the same id for all windows! What could be wrong now? Thanks!!!!

Comment: Hi dessert, that's weird, here only one PID is given for all my windows, even the active one. I don't understand! Also, the number of PIDs is higher than the number of consoles open.

Comment: Hi, using `--onlyvisible` option it returns the right number of windows. But still, all have the same PID